# How to change camera direction in osmdroid?

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I would like to know if there is a way to change camera direction for a perspective mapview? (Z-Axis)

It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VP6dx.png).

Answer (score 0):

There's a few examples in the sample app for setting the map rotation. Here's some code

`mMapView.setMapOrientation(90f);`

And a link to the source

https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/MapView.java#L575

Comment: Thanks. But I mean change camera direction in z axis, it makes the map look like perspective projection:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/VP6dx.png

Comment: You don't. It's not supported

Answer (score 0):

This feature (as of now) is not supported by OSMDroid. To perform an Z-Axis tilting on the mapview, you will need to look for alternatives elsewhere.